# Show the content when user scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello please check this site you 'll see that next content will be loaded automatically as you scroll down.

http://wallbase.net/search

I ve searched the google but couldn't figure its name.

Any example//tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Infinite Scroll jQuery Plugin](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/).

And some more tutorials on the same subject:

http://www.9lessons.info/2009/07/load-data-while-scroll-with-jquery-php.html

[http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/load-content-while-scrolling-with-jquery/](https://web.archive.org/web/20160304031317/http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/load-content-while-scrolling-with-jquery/)

Good luck!